# Khaos Control cron tasks not triggering with other cron tasks (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

We have additional module in our Magento 1.9 for Khaos Control which allows Magento to communicate with Khaos for stock and orders etc

The functionality works fine when manually triggered but not when set to run on the cron schedules.

Our other crons are working fine (such as Sage Pay & emails), and Keystone Software who develop the module are frankly no help as they are more interested in selling us their alternative to Magento than helping fix the issue so I'm currently hoping someone out there has experienced similar and can provide me some pointers!

Comment: Which extension are you using to connect magento with khaos control?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like the bigger problem was the cron module itself. We've done some investigating since and managed to get it working. It looks like the magneto cron files were corrupt